# Writing list of lists with arbitrary length to file

Tags: python

I have a list of form

```
lssample=[  [ [A,B],[C] ] ,[ [D],[E,F] ],[ [G,H],[I] ]]
```

What is the most efficient way to write this into a file in the form

```
A,B : C
D: E,F
G,H : I
```

Note that the lengths are arbitrary for sublists. The below code only writes the list in the form it is (With brackets). Is there a pythonic way of writing this into a file ?

```
with open("output1.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(lssample)
```

Comment: This is not a csv file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a pretty simple format to just roll-your-own writer, something like:

```
In [2]: data = [[['A','B'], ['C']], [['D'],['E','F']], [['G','H'], ['I']]]

In [3]: import io

In [4]: with io.StringIO() as f:
    ...:     for record in data:
    ...:         left, right  = map(",".join, record)
    ...:         f.write(f"{left} : {right}\n")
    ...:     final = f.getvalue()
    ...:

In [5]: print(final)
A,B : C
D : E,F
G,H : I
```

Note, `io.StringIO` is just a in-memory buffer that acts like a file for the purpose of easy-illustration. You would just do:

```
with open("output1.txt", "w") as f:
    ...
```

And of course, you don't need `final = f.getvalue()`. Also, I'm using Python 3.6 f-strings. If you don't have that, you can use:

```
f.write("{} : {}".format(left, right)
```

Comment: Only one tiny imporvement proposal: tuple unpacking in the head of the `for` loop, so `for a,b in data:`. +1.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually, I went with unpacking with `map(','.join, record)`.

Answer (score 3):

The following string is what you are looking for (add spaces around the colon if desired):

```
output = "\n".join(','.join(head) + ":" + ','.join(tail) \
                   for head, tail in lssample)
print(output)
#A,B:C
#D:E,F
#G,H:I
```

Just write it to a file.

Answer (score 3):

use a `join`,

```
fp = open('file_name','w')
txt = '\n'.join([','.join(i)+ ' : ' + ','.join(j) for i,j in lssample]) 
fp.write(txt)
fp.close()
```

Result:,

```
In [10]: print txt
A,B : C
D : E,F
G,H : I
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `print` and a little helper function for brevity (which also happens to reduce name lookups):

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fmt = ','.join
    for fst, snd in lssample:
        print(fmt(fst), ':', fmt(snd), file=fout)
```